# Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package

Tags: asp.net-core, package

Can someone help with this issue?

Not able to figure out what's wrong. It was working earlier , after my machine crashed and I restored code it didn't work after that.

Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.2 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies 2.1.2 does not support any target frameworks.    BrightSteps.Web.Api C:\Code\BrightStepsBackend\BrightSteps.Web.Api\BrightSteps.Web.Api.csproj   1

Comment: Have you tried to update your vs and your SDK. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`  contains `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies `.Check your dependencies and make sure they have same version.

Comment: yes updated SDK but few more things needed to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me to resolve this issues.

1. Clear nuget package on my machine. Its typically on C:[UserName].nuget

Updated latest SDKS for asp.net core

Removed package Microsoft.AspnetCore.All and re-installed again, which was causing issue.